# How to update an Eclipse plugin from a password protected site?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, mercurial

I read on [this site(http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) that I need to "sign-up" in order to download the Eclipse plugin for Mercurial. I signed up but nothing appears to happen. When I try to download the plugin by going to Help => Install new software and typing in the site address (http://cbes.javaforge.com/update), Eclipse states it's unable to connect, "Error Contacting Site: No software site found ..." (I don't get to type in a password / username).

I then read on [this site](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/dvcs-install-gitegit-and-mercurialhgeclipse/) that the plugin is also available here:

http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg.wiki/update_site/stable

The question is and what I don't get is how is a password protected "Software Site" supposed to work with Eclipse. When was I supposed to be asked for a password / username during this process?

Answer (score 1):

Normal a pop up should prompt for login credentials, after you entered the update site URL.
If no credential promt appear's, it may be that there are already credentials stored within your eclipse secure storage (the same location for all installed eclipse derivate's you run.)

You find such information's at:
Preferences -> Security -> Secure Storage -> [Tab] "Contents"

[image: Find stored login credentials here]