# Is it possible to have a password protected Eclipse update site?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse update site currently set up on a private network. I'd like to make it available to an external customer, but not to the world at large. Does Eclipse support authentication/authorization for update sites?

Obviously I could just zip the contents of the site and email it to them, but I'd like to see if there's a simpler process.

Searching StackOverflow, I've only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815613/how-to-update-an-eclipse-plugin-from-a-password-protected-site) question, which doesn't shed much light on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The best option I've found so far is using a password protected FTP server. Eclipse was happy with a `ftp://username:password@server` URL.

I tried to use FTP-TLS but couldn't get it to work.